# how can "extend" html and controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I want to keep a menu html showing all the time.
and mapaBase with their respective html and controller, too.
I want to extend the functionality of controladorMapa to the inicial and movilpedido state.

I got a blank screen

```
        .state('menu', {
            url: "/menu",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/menu.html"

        })

           .state('menu.mapaBase', {
               url: "/mapaBase",
               abstract: true,
               templateUrl: "templates/mapaBase.html",
               controller: 'controladorMapa'
           })

               .state('menu.mapaBase.inicial', {
                   url: "/inicial",
                   templateUrl: "templates/mapaInicial.html"
                   controller: 'controladorInicial'

                })

               .state('menu.mapaBase.movilPedido', {
                  url: "/movilPedido",
                  templateUrl: "templates/movilPedido.html"
                  controller: 'controladorMovil'
               })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a directive to extend html and some functionality.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

But if you just want a fixed menu maybe the best choice is create a template for your app/website instead of a component to add everywhere.